# Recommended key size and type for GnuPG?

Tags: windows, gnupg

[A Practical Introduction to GNU Privacy Guard in Windows](http://www.glump.net/howto/cryptography/practical-introduction-to-gnu-privacy-guard-in-windows) recommends DSA and ElGamal, but I would like to know if RSA is good enough to use these days, and if so, what minimum key size should I use? Is it ok to use SHA-256 for signing (for compatibility with e-mail clients)?

Also, beside [e-ignite: Key Types](http://www.e-ignite.co.uk/html/key_types.html), can you point to other sources for this subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RSA/DSA minimum today is 1024 bit actually, so Elleptical Curves becoming more in use since they are faster and using shorter keys.

To have a similar security as AES256 you will need at least 3072 bit (384 bytes) key...

Email clients using certificates nowadays - so it's separate thing (X.509), but for using with RSA/DSA most common option is SHA-1 (somewhat weak now).

I recommend study of:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509
- http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2264

Comment: He was specifically asking about gnupg an opensource implementation of OpenPGP. PGP/OpenPGP does not use certificates (that's S/MIME).

Comment: *To have a similar security as AES256 you will need at least 3 kilobytes key* You mean a 256 *bit* long AES key provides roughly the same security, that a 3 *kilobyte* ([24576 bit](http://www.google.com/search?q=1+bit+in+kilobyte)) long RSA key does? Weren't you thinking about a 3072 bit long RSA key instead? Given that GnuPG can generate RSA keys with a length around 4096 bit, your statement feels wrong. (I'm just asking, because I'm not *exactly* sure about—only *pretty* sure—and I don't want to correct your otherwise good answer based on false assumptions.)

Answer (score 5):

I know the topic is old, but at this time, DSA 1024 is considered to be too weak, as is SHA-1.
You should use RSA 2048 (for signing and encryption) and SHA256 (for digest). Normally, the symmetric algorithm used is AES256, which is good enough.

When encrypting, GPG gzips the data, creates an AES256 key and encrypts the data with it. It then encrypts the AES key with the recipient RSA or ElGamal public key and sends the encrypted AES key + the encrypted data in a pack.

RSA 2048 is said to protect data until 2015 or so, and RSA 4096 would protect data until 2020, based on the predicted computer power at that time. (I'm not totally sure about the dates, but it is logical that a 4096 bit key would be harder to crack than a 2048 bit one)

Comment: How about compatibilty issues? When I generate an `RSA 4096`key in Thunderbird+Enigmail, can it be used with all common email clients nowadays?

Comment: I think that RSA 4096 is available pretty everywhere nowadays

Answer (score 2):

SHA-1 is weak, but not fully broken. SHA-256 is just an extension to SHA-1, currently it's probably also weaker than first thought (given the same weakness is thought to affect the whole sha family), however it still requires a lot of computing power to get a match.

Anyway, in terms of digital signatures, this becomes less of a problem due to the way that's just the final step. There is still encryption first.

As for key size whether RSA or ElGammel/DSA I would recommend 2048 bit keys anyway now.
the difference is RSA is based on factorial math while ElGammel/DSA is based on logarithmic math, neither can necessarily be considered better or worse (to not though i that elliptic curve based stuff is closely related to the logarithms stuff).

Comment: SHA-256 is a part of the SHA-2 family, which is distinctly different from SHA-1. It is not *just* an extension. The same weakness is definitely **not** thought to extend to SHA-2.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend RSA/RSA 4096 with AES256 and SHA512

Answer (score -1):

GPG can only use RSA for signing, not encryption. The default is DSA/Elgamal 1024/2048. The Elgamal default key length used to be 1024, but someone must have decided that was not secure enough. People on the GPG mailing list say that most people shouldn't need more than 2048.

I'm less clear on the various signing algorithms. I know there are issues with SHA-1, but how does this relate to DSA/RSA?

I've had the same key for years that uses the above default values. I don't use it much, but am wondering whether generating a new one is justified.

Comment: gpg --gen-key presents the following options: RSA and RSA (default) / DSA and Elgamal / DSA (sign only) / RSA (sign only)

Answer (score -3):

If you don't know, you should use the GPG defaults! (This is how the authors have intended it.)